# How to connect OpenMPI library to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, openmpi

I need to connect OpenMPI library to Visual Studio 2015. I can't use other liblaries instead of OpenMPI. I setup OpenMPI_v1.6.2-1_win32.exe and specified:
Include Directories: C:\Program Files\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-win32\include
Library Directories: C:\Program Files\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-win32\lib
Additional Dependencies: libmpi.lib
Open MP Support: Yes
When I try to compile the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int ProcNum, ProcRank, RecvRank;
    MPI_Status Status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcNum);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ProcRank);
    if (ProcRank == 0) {
        // Действия, выполняемые только процессом с рангом 0
        printf("\n Hello from process %3d", ProcRank);
        for (int i = 1; i < ProcNum; i++) {
            MPI_Recv(&RecvRank, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE,
                MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Status);
            printf("\n Hello from process %3d", RecvRank);
        }
    }
    else // Сообщение, отправляемое всеми процессами, 
         // кроме процесса с рангом 0 
        MPI_Send(&ProcRank, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio show errors:

> 1>------ Build started: Project: OpenMPISample, Configuration: Debug
>   Win32 ------ 1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   _ompi_mpi_comm_world 1>Source.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _ompi_mpi_int 1>C:\Users\Andriy\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\OpenMPISample\Debug\OpenMPISample.exe : fatal error
>   LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

How to connect OpenMPI library to Visual Studio 2015 correctly? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure your project is not configured as 64-bit. Linking 32-bit libraries into 64-bit executables doesn't work.

Comment: Also, Open MPI comes as a set of libraries and you might need to add more of them as dependencies. The installer ships with several compiler wrappers. Run `mpicc -showme:link` in a command prompt to see which libraries are needed.

Comment: The question might be more topical on openmpi mail list. I thought openmpi abandoned visual studio target after Microsoft made their version of mpich free.  Openmpi does support cygwin.